# smartest way to use config /etc/sudoers for www-data

Tags: php, sudo, sudoers

I want to ask what is the best or smartest way to use /etc/sudoers for www-data if you need sometimes the exec or shell_exec function for cp, mv or start some python files. Is www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL the only way or how would you config such problem? thx

Comment: This is a _very_ bad idea. It would mean if anyone somehow managed to trigger some PHP code through the web server (some kind of RCE), they can take over the entire server since they can perform any SUDO command without needing a password. Depending on what the files are, you could give www-data access to those, or you could work with queues. Let PHP add the action to a queue, then have some script (could be called using CRON every few seconds, or different service running as a daemon) read and perform the actions in the queue. Then you can limit and verify the actions it can perform.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Although it's a bit of a "frame challenge", I think that's the best answer to this question. If you move your comment to the Answer section, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @IMSoP - Ty. Added it as an answer.

Comment: @M.Eriksson ty for that. so its better to write an python file to move, del or do what ever i need to do with some uploaded files and set the permissions for that python file under sudoers, right?

Comment: @trash2 "sudo" should not need to be involved at all - change the permissions of the relevant files so that the regular web server / scripting user can manipulate them. It should be extremely rare for any scripted action to need to be performed as root, and generally that would be a script running entirely in a privileged state, like a deployment agent or system maintenance cron task. "sudo" is a tool for _interactive_ maintenance of a system, and has to be forced to even operate non-interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to set `www-data` as a sudoer, even more so as a sudoer without password. It would mean if anyone somehow managed to trigger some PHP code through the web server (any kind of Remove Code Execution vulnerability), they can take over the entire server since they can perform commands as SUDO without needing a password on your entire server.

Here are a couple of possible alternatives:

- Depending on what the files are, you could give `www-data` the needed permission to those specific file.
- Work with queues. Let PHP add the action to a queue, then have some script (could be called using CRON every few seconds, or you create a different service running as a daemon) read and perform the actions in the queue. Then you can also limit and verify the actions it can perform before it performs them.